# wkhtmltopdf exclude css files from PDF but show in HTML

Tags: wkhtmltopdf, django-wkhtmltopdf

I was working with wkhmtltopdf and found that I have a problem with it.
I am using the html page to also preview the content in a browser prior to converting to PDF.

But to make it more readable in my preview, I have added some css on the page: (In javascript/jQuery on document ready)

```
  $(document).ready(function () {
    if(window.location.href.indexOf("preview") > -1 && window.location.href.indexOf(".pdf") == -1) {
      appendCSStoHtml();
    }
  });

  function appendCSStoHtml() {
    $("body").css({"background-color":" #F0F8FF"});

    $("#previewHtml").css({
      "margin-left":"15%",
      "margin-right":"15%",
      "margin-top":"15px",
      "max-width":"1024px"});

    $("#previewHtml > h2").css({"margin-left":" 15px"});
  }
```

So this is all good and dandy, but when I generate my PDF based on this HTML page, then the css is also renderend inside my PDF and the outlining and background are also present inside the PDF.

I don't want this to happen, I only want my css style elements to be renderen on the HTML page and not inside the PDF.

How can I achieve this?

I tried with the following:

```
  $(document).ready(function () {
    if(window.location.href.indexOf("preview") > -1 && window.location.href.indexOf(".pdf") == -1) {
      appendCSStoHtml();
    }
  });
```

But that did not matter.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

it's me again.

Not sure if there is something that resembles what I am looking for.
Thus I made my own.

I added a page parameter and check this in the code to see if it's `true` or `false`:

```
<script type="text/javascript">

  $(document).ready(function () {
    var url_string = window.location.href;
    var url = new URL(url_string);
    var renderCss = url.searchParams.get("renderCss");

    if(renderCss == 'true') {
      appendCSStoHtml();
    }
  });

  function appendCSStoHtml() {
    $("body").css({"background-color":" #F0F8FF"});

    $("#previewHtml").css({
      "margin-left":"15%",
      "margin-right":"15%",
      "margin-top":"15px",
      "max-width":"1024px"});

    $("#previewHtml > h2").css({"margin-left":" 15px"});
  }

</script>
```